# Registering new feature test

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I'm creating a new test

> php artisan make:test

I wrote new test in new file but it doesn't work (no matter what I write, any time I has success testing). Propably I must register this test. Where I can do that?

Comment: can u share your test?

Comment: I use default test with the difference that I change assertStatus to 404 (I want to force failed test but any time I have success). Even I wrote anything bad syntax. It doesn't matter what I wrote at this file. So propably I must register this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Phpunit to register your test cases there are some requirements.

Inherits from `TestCase`. In raw PHP projects `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`. `Laravel` already extends this and you would extend `Tests\TestCase;` So an example would be.

```
use Tests\TestCase;

class YourTest extends TestCase {

}
```

Secondly you either need to prefix your test cases with a specific naming `test*`, so you test cases should look like this.

```
function testYourModelProperty() {
    $this->assertSame(1, 1);
}
```

Alternatively you can use an annotation, if you don't want to prefix your naming.

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function yourCase()
{
    $this->assertSame(1, 1);
}
```